# it is good to use a macros to hide a typename?

Tags: c++, generics

Actually I want to "hide" a typename declaration. It is due in my code this same type name appears several times (actually it is part of many base classes), and wow it is meaningful, it makes the code more readable.

I have the question: Is good to "hide" (substitute) that typename using a macros?

Example:

```cpp
#define __NodeType typename _NodeTy

template <typename T, __NodeType>
class TheClassName {
//...
```

#### Edit:

First, I did not knew that the `__` double underscore implies 'part of standard library'. Second, the comment of [idclev 463035818](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4117728/idclev-463035818) makes sense, I will still need to use `_NodeTy` so there is no benefit, is useless and redundant. Third, I declared that `_NodeTy`, it is not part of the standard library and I am not using external libraries either.

Finally, many thanks

Comment: *it makes the code more readable* -- Then  you run into a compiler that uses your double underscored name for its own internal purposes, and your program either doesn't compile, doesn't link, or runs erratically.

Comment: if you do that you still need both `__NodeType` and `_NodeTy` so I fail to see the benefit

Comment: i know it is tempting to use macros as a way to make code shorter, but you have to consider that it might be readable to you, but not to anybody else. You can use macros to invent your own language but it isnt c++ anymore

Comment: Every other C++ programmer is going to expect to see `typename` or `class` in front of a template type parameter. By hiding that, you will confuse other programmers.

Comment: _it is good to use a macros to hide a typename?_  No, it's the opposite of good.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> it is good to use a macros to hide a typename?

No. It is bad and it obfuscates the source.

`__NodeType` doesn't in any way convey that `_NodeTy` has been declared.

P.S. Both `__NodeType` and `_NodeTy` identifiers are reserved to the language implementation. You should not define them in your own code, or else the behaviour of the program will be undefined.

Comment: To clarify, `__NodeType` and `_NodeTy` are reserved because they use either a double-underscore anywhere or because they start with an underscore followed by a capital letter. Identifiers containing these are reserved for the compiler's and standard library's internal use.